# Using a python script to delete a file that already exists

Tags: python, backup, os.walk, python-os

I am trying to write a backup script and for part of it I am thinking of deleting existing files with the same name in the directory I am backing up the data into so I don't have thousands of files with the same name. I want to delete the old file and then backup the newer version of that file. I plan on using a crontab to do a backup once or twice a week. So far I have the following:

```
for files in os.walk(BACKUP_FROM_PATH):
    if files.isfile():
        if files.name in BACKUP_TO_PATH:  # checks if a file with the same name is already in the backup dir
            os.remove(files)
            removed.append(files)
    elif files.isdir():
        for files2 in os.walk(files):
            if files2.isfile():
                if files2.name in BACKUP_FROM_PATH:
                    os.remove(files2)
                    removed.append(files2)
return removed
```

I also have the following alternative:

```
for files, dirs, root in os.walk(BACKUP_FROM_PATH):
    for currentFile in files:
        if currentFile in BACKUP_FROM_PATH):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, currentFile))
            removed.append(currentFile)
return removed
```

I am curious as to the difference between doing simply os.remove and doing os.remove(os.path.join(root, currentFile)). I have seen people mention both ways and want to know if one is preferred or how they behave differently.

Comment: That is a terrible idea my friend. Just use `rsync -avr`